# Using JavaScript inside a Eclipse plugin

Tags: javascript, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

It is possible to use **JavaScript** inside a view of a Eclipse Plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default eclipse runs on java in a JVM.  But JVMs have more and more support for dynamic scripting languages.  You can always use [org.mozilla.javascript](http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20120526062928/) so your view can implement parts in javascript.  The linke I've included to eclipse Orbit builds are versions that have been OSGi-ified so they can be used easily in eclipse.

Comment: Ok, first thanks for your advice. After you write the option org.mozilla.javascript I do some searchs in google and found the the [Rhino: JavaScript for Java](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/) and the [Nashorn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nashorn_(JavaScript_engine)). The authors of Nashorn said "Nashorn performance is three to five times faster and the engine is five times smaller than Rhino. One of the problems with using Rhino is it's considerably slower than a lot of the current JavaScripts that are out there.". Do you agree with this phrases? Nashorn will be released with Java 8.

Comment: I don't know.  I've had occasion to use Rhino, but never compared it to anything else.  I do know that Rhino runs on earlier than java 8, but you can use whatever javascript engine that runs on a JVM that you would like.