# How to develop Eclipse RCP, Eclipse plugins with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

How to develop Eclipse RCP, Eclipse plugins with JavaScript?

I know that [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) runtime is based on [Equinox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equinox_%28OSGi%29) and is wholly implemented in Java.

The question is **to what extent JavaScript code can be used** for developing Eclipse RCP, Eclipse plugins.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: We are developing Eclipse Node.js IDE (Nodeclipse - Enide). And I feel like if we do everything with Java, then Node.js developers without Java knowledge can't help. Hope to find way, that Node.js developers can contribute to Node.js IDE based on Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [Rhino](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rhino).

Comment: Rhino is Java engine to run JavaScript. Could Google V8 be better?

Comment: Of course V8 is better, but you want to use it in Eclipse, which to my knowledge only works with Java implementations.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11018009/using-javascript-inside-a-eclipse-plugin) also helps.

Comment: Yeah, that is closer... Now hoping somebody, who uses JS in Eclipse development, can share "to what extent"

Comment: Now there is Nashorn on horizon.

Answer (score 0):

With the existing RCP infrastructure I don't think that is possible to write native widgets. You can however create a view with browser inside and use javascript (you would need a webserver). [There](http://www.vogella.com/blog/2009/12/21/javascript-swt/) is a small tutorial how to use the browser widget.

A long shot: You can also take a look at Eclipse RAP. They use the RCP infrastructure to create web applications.

Another option would be to use code to code transformation (javascript to java).

Comment: Thanks aphex. I am exploring browser widget. The link you gave I have seen already. It doesn't go well with Eclipse 4 runtime. 

Eclipse RAP is for running Eclipse RCP code in browser, like GWT. Solution becomes too complicated.

Comment: Code transformation is vague, generated code will always be nightmare to use.

Comment: I know and that won't be easy to be accomplished. The easiest way is the usage of browser widget.